# Binomial Tree Plot in R

Tags: r, plot, data-visualization

I have a little issue with the binomial tree plot in R; I'm using the package fOptions. Given St=39, K=40, T1=0.5, r=0.02, sigma=0.2, n=2, I use the following code:

```
CRRTree<- BinomialTreeOption(TypeFlag='ce',39,40,0.5,0.02,0.02,0.2,2)
BinomialTreePlot(CRRTree)
```

and the corresponding plot is

[image: Binomial Tree Plot]

I have two problems.

First: I want that the x axis starts from zero and goes to 2

Second: I don't undestand why the upper value of the tree is not showed in the picture; how can I fix it? 
Thank you very much.

**EDIT**: I solved the second problem in the easiest way, I think. It was sufficient to code the plot in this way:

```
BinomialTreePlot(CRRTree,ylim=c(-2,2.5))
```

There is an easy way to solve also the problem of making the tree starts from 0?

Answer (score 2):

You will have to modify the code for the BinomialTreePlot function. For example, you could try something like that:

```
my_BinomialTreePlot<-function (BinomialTreeValues, dx = -0.025, dy = 0.4, cex = 1, 
    digits = 2, ...) 
{
    Tree = round(BinomialTreeValues, digits = digits)
    depth = ncol(Tree)
    plot(x = c(0, depth-1), y = c(-depth + 1, depth - 1), type = "n", 
        col = 0, ...)
    points(x = 0, y = 0)
    text(0 + dx, 0 + dy, deparse(Tree[1, 1]), cex = cex)
    for (i in 1:(depth - 1)) {
        y = seq(from = -i, by = 2, length = i + 1)
        x = rep(i, times = length(y)) + 0
        points(x, y, col = 1)
        for (j in 1:length(x)) text(x[j] + dx, y[j] + dy, deparse(Tree[length(x) + 
            1 - j, i + 1]), cex = cex)
        y = (-i):i
        x = rep(c(i, i-1), times = 2 * i)[1:length(y)]
        lines(x, y, col = 2)
    }
    invisible()
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
CRRTree<- BinomialTreeOption(TypeFlag='ce',39,40,0.5,0.02,0.02,0.2,2)
my_BinomialTreePlot(CRRTree,xlim=c(-0.1,2), ylim=c(-2.5,2.5))
```

[image]

Comment: This works perfectly, but it's a little bit complicated for me. I solved the second problem in a very easy way, do you have any suggestions to solve problem n. 1 without using a long code?